# Xpath - get text from all h1, h3 p tags within a div

Tags: php, dom, html, xpath

I'm currently using the queries below to extract the text within the `<h1>` `<p>` and `<h3>` tags.

```
$xpath->query("//div[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' grid_9 alpha omega newscontainer arena ')]/h1");
$xpath->query("//div[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' grid_9 alpha omega newscontainer arena ')]/p");
$xpath->query("//div[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' grid_9 alpha omega newscontainer arena ')]/h3");
```

They do sometimes come in different orders though, so i would like to catch them in order of appearance in the html. I did use

```
$xpath->query('//h1 | //p | //h3');
```

and that worked well to, but also caught some `<p>` tags outside of the div class specified above. Using them in sequence didn't work at all. Is there a way to combine these queries into one?

Basically extracting all h1,p and h3 tags within a specific div class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you try

```
$xpath->query("//div[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' grid_9 alpha omega newscontainer arena ')]/*[local-name()='h1' or local-name()='p' or local-name()='h3']");
```

This should give you the nodes in the order of their appearance restricted to children of the `div` parent and also in XPath 1.0 which I assume is an unmentioned prerequisite.

Answer (score 0):

When you use // will match any element with this tagname

You must be more specific and i suggest you

```
$xpath->query('//div/h1 | //div/p | //div/h3');
```

Comment: This solved it, thank you. The queries do get massive though :) `$xpath1->query("//div[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' grid_9 alpha omega newscontainer arena ')]/h1 | //div[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' grid_9 alpha omega newscontainer arena ')]/p | //div[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' grid_9 alpha omega newscontainer arena ')]/h3");`

Comment: @MGJ: It would be interesting to know if this query preserves the order of the tags as they are found in the document.

Comment: @Marcus-rickert: It did, at least with the data i'm dealing with now. Both these answers provided the same result.